# Form not posting to database - PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm fairly new to PHP and designing a small blog. I'm trying to submit a form to create a new post but it isn't working and I can't figure out why. I've compared it to my working code for the register form and it seems the same. I'm not getting any errors, it's just reloading the page and not posting to the database.

View - v_newpost.php

```
    <article>
    <?php
    if (!isset ($_SESSION['username']))
    {
    ?>
    <span class="alert">Please login to create a post.</span>
    <?php
    }

    else 
    {
    ?>
    <form class="newpost" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Submit a new post</legend>
    <?php if ($error['alert'] != '') { echo "<span class='alert'>".$error['alert']."</span>";} ?>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $input['title']; ?>" required autofocus>
    </li>
    <li>
    <label for="content">Content:</label>
    <textarea id="content" name="content" rows=6 value="<?php echo $input['content']; ?>"></textarea>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class=postbutton>Publish</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</article>
```

newpost.php

```
    <?php
    require_once 'includes/connection.php';

$error['alert'] = '';
$input['title'] = '';
$input['content'] = '';

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if ($_POST['title'] == '' || $_POST['content'] == '')
    {
        $error['alert'] = 'Please give your post a title and content.';

        $input['title'] = $_POST['title'];
        $input['content'] = $_POST['content'];

        include_once('v_newpost.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $input['title'] = htmlentities($_POST['title'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $input['content'] = htmlentities($_POST['content'], ENT_QUOTES);

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (title, content) VALUES (?,?)"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $input['title'], $input['content']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

            $error['alert'] = '';
            $input['title'] = '';
            $input['content'] = '';

            header('Location: index.php');
        }
        else
        {
            $error['alert'] = 'Failed to create post';
        }
    }

}
else
{
    include_once('v_newpost.php');
}


?>
```

I'm sure it's probably something stupid, but I've looked over it so many times and can't understand why it isn't working...

Comment: This actually wasn't the problem as the form posts back to the same page if left blank. I hadn't given my submit button a name as greut pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will never be true since you have no form element with `name="submit"`.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I was reading 'button type="submit"' and didn't realise I hadn't named it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set the action of the form to point to newpost.php

Comment: No actions mean that the form will be sent to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You need an action in your form. Try:

```
<form class="newpost" action="newpost.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

In newpost.php you have 
   if (isset($_POST['submit']))
It'll not work because you do not send anything with name submit.